# What happens if you copy someone else's question?

Tags: support, asking-questions

Will copying someone else's question:

1. still get an answer
2. get marked as [closed]
3. get marked as [duplicate]
4. still receive upvotes (but no answers)?

I might need help with this question as I have copied someone else's question just so because it hasn't received any answers yet and I really want an answer to that specific question. The question I want to ask again ([How do I replace a program written as a sequenced stream of state transitions with scalaz-stream?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26974988/how-do-i-replace-a-program-written-as-a-sequenced-stream-of-state-transitions-wi)) has no answers at all but has received 79 upvotes and since it was asked 4 years ago, I don't know if the user is active, therefore I want to ask the question again myself.

Comment: The duplicate question wants good answers to a question that doesn't have any but still has answers. My question states that I need answers to a question that doesn't have any answers at all.

Comment: The solution is still explained in the duplicate: put up a bounty.

Comment: For a question that hasn't had any answers in 4 years?

Comment: @user11206537, Yes...  Old questions can be given bounties.  You might be shocked how effective bounties can be.  I have only put up [one bounty](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44752645/where-are-the-gains-using-numba-coming-from-for-pure-numpy-code), but it took a question with no answers and few votes to one a question with a great answer, and 18 votes.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In all likelihood, it will be closed as a duplicate of the previous question and deleted. We do *not* want exact duplicate questions to be answered, and usually they aren't. If the duplicate is easy-to-find, it will probably be downvoted for lack of research effort, not upvoted.

If you found a question without a good answer, there are still ways to get it answered. See: [How do I get attention for one of my own questions without a good answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7046/how-do-i-get-attention-for-one-of-my-own-questions-without-a-good-answer)

Comment: It is actually highly unlikely it will be marked a duplicate because with the original not having any answers normal users can't close it as a duplicate at all.